# Adding image to comment box

Tags: javascript, php

Thanks for your time guys.
I have the following code working for my commenting system though I can't really be sure about the security for now. But I need your help guys in :

1. Allowing anyone that comment to add their image to their comment whether registered users or Visitors
2. Building the inside comment or reply box. This is what I got.
3. Comment for comment counter

Here is the PHP code for the comment:

```
<?php 
// Connect to the database
include('config.php'); 
$id_post = "1"; //the post or the page id
?>
<div class="cmt-container" >
    <?php 
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id_post = '$id_post'") or die(mysql_error());;
    while($affcom = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){ 
        $name = $affcom['name'];
        $email = $affcom['email'];
        $comment = $affcom['comment'];
        $date = $affcom['date'];

        // Get gravatar Image 
        // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
        $default = "mm";
        $size = 35;
        $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/".md5(strtolower(trim($email)))."?d=".$default."&s=".$size;

    ?>
    <div class="cmt-cnt">
        <a href="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>"  height="250" /></a>
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span data-utime="1371248446" class="com-dt"><?php echo $date; ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p>
                <?php echo $comment; ?>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->
    <?php } ?>


    <div class="new-com-bt">
        <span>Write a comment ...</span>
    </div>
    <div class="new-com-cnt">
        <input type="text" id="name-com" name="name-com" value="" placeholder="Your name" />
        <input type="text" id="mail-com" name="mail-com" value="" placeholder="Your e-mail adress" />
        <textarea class="the-new-com"></textarea>
        <div class="bt-add-com">Post comment</div>
        <div class="bt-cancel-com">Cancel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end of comments container "cmt-container" -->


<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){ 
        //alert(event.timeStamp);
        $('.new-com-bt').click(function(event){    
            $(this).hide();
            $('.new-com-cnt').show();
            $('#name-com').focus();
        });

        /* when start writing the comment activate the "add" button */
        $('.the-new-com').bind('input propertychange', function() {
           $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:0.6});
           var checklength = $(this).val().length;
           if(checklength){ $(".bt-add-com").css({opacity:1}); }
        });

        /* on clic  on the cancel button */
        $('.bt-cancel-com').click(function(){
            $('.the-new-com').val('');
            $('.new-com-cnt').fadeOut('fast', function(){
                $('.new-com-bt').fadeIn('fast');
            });
        });

        // on post comment click 
        $('.bt-add-com').click(function(){
            var theCom = $('.the-new-com');
            var theName = $('#name-com');
            var theMail = $('#mail-com');

            if( !theCom.val()){ 
                alert('You need to write a comment!'); 
            }else{ 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/add-comment.php",
                    data: 'act=add-com&id_post='+<?php echo $id_post; ?>+'&name='+theName.val()+'&email='+theMail.val()+'&comment='+theCom.val(),
                    success: function(html){
                        theCom.val('');
                        theMail.val('');
                        theName.val('');
                        $('.new-com-cnt').hide('fast', function(){
                            $('.new-com-bt').show('fast');
                            $('.new-com-bt').before(html);  
                        })
                    }  
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

And the Ajax Script :

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
if($_POST['act'] == 'add-com'):
    $name = htmlentities($name);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $comment = htmlentities($comment);

    // Connect to the database
    include('../config.php'); 

    // Get gravatar Image 
    // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
    $default = "mm";
    $size = 35;
    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . $default . "&s=" . $size;

    if(strlen($name) <= '1'){ $name = 'Guest';}
    //insert the comment in the database
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (name, email, comment, id_post)VALUES( '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$id_post')");
    if(!mysql_errno()){
?>

    <div class="cmt-cnt">
        <img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" alt="" />
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span  class="com-dt"><?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i'); ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->

    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```